# Scala: k fold cross validation

Tags: scala

I want to do k-fold cross validation. Essentially we are given a bunch of data `allData`. Suppose we partition our input into "k" cluster and put it in `groups`.

The desired output is a `trainAndTestDataList: List[(Iterable[T], Iterable[T])]`, where the `List`is of size "k". The "i"th element of the `trainAndTestDataList` is a tuple like (A, B), where A should be the "i"th element of `groups` and B should be all elements of `groups` except the "i"th one, concatenated.

Any ideas on implementing this efficiently?

```
val allData: Iterable[T] = ... // we get the data from somewhere 

val groupSize = Math.ceil(allData.size / k).toInt
val groups = allData.grouped(groupSize).toList

val trainAndTestDataList = ... // fill out this part
```

One thing to keep in mind is that `allData` can be very long, however "k" is very small (say 5). So it is very crucial to keep all the data vectors as `Iterator` (and not `List`, `Seq`, etc).

Update: Here is how I did (and I am not happy about it):

```
val trainAndTestDataList = {
  (0 until k).map{ fold =>
    val (a,b) = groups.zipWithIndex.partition{case (g, idx) => idx == fold}
    (a.unzip._1.flatten.toIterable, b.unzip._1.flatten.toIterable)
  }
}
```

Reasons I don't like it:

1. much twisted especially after `partition` where I do an `unzip`, then `._1` and `flatten`. I think one should be able to do a better job.
2. Although `a` is a `Iterable[T]`, the output of `a.unzip._1.flatten.` is a `List[T]`, I think. This is no good, since the number of the element in this list might be very large.

Comment: This is looking very like a "gimme the code" question. What have you considered?

Comment: ok, I will update it with solution in a minute.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, in `trainedAndTestDataList`, `A` is the slice from `(i-1)i*groupSize` to `i*groupSize` of the original `allData`, and `B` is the concatenation of slices `0... (i-1)*groupSize -1` and `i*groupSIze+1 ... allData.length` (i.e. `allData` without the `A` elements). Correct? Do you have to put the first `groupSize` in the first cluster or can you put the first element in `cluster1`, the second in `cluster2` etc?

Comment: If you can split into clusters as you go, you can define two Iterator subclasses that return every `k`th element and everything-except-every-`k`th element for a neat solution. I'm at work but if I get a chance will knock something out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try that operation

```
implicit class TeeSplitOp[T](data: Iterable[T]) {
  def teeSplit(count: Int): Stream[(Iterable[T], Iterable[T])] = {
    val size = data.size

    def piece(i: Int) = i * size / count

    Stream.range(0, size - 1) map { i =>
      val (prefix, rest) = data.splitAt(piece(i))
      val (test, postfix) = rest.splitAt(piece(i + 1) - piece(i))
      val train = prefix ++ postfix
      (test, train)
    }
  }
}
```

This split will be as lazy as `splitAt` and `++` are within your collection type.

You can try it with

```
1 to 10 teeSplit 3 force
```

Comment: It is lazy (assuming that the particular subclass of `Iterable` you pass in is lazy), but all the test/train sets will eventually be memoized (hence taking up space in memory), and I don't believe that's what the OP had in mind.

Comment: Also `Iterables` don't generally guarantee a particular iteration order, so multiple applications of `teeSplit` could potentially result in different sequences of test/train sets. Because of this it seems like it might be a good idea to further constrain the type of `data` to `Seq[T]` and then make a `Stream[T]` (to get laziness) from that internally. But this still doesn't overcome the issue I mentioned in my previous comment.

Comment: @jasonl I would argue about stream memoising trouble. First - any sufficient large stream fold shows that if top `Stream` itself is not held by some `val` its used prefix would be efficiently GCed while traversing to the tail. Second - if **`k`** is sufficiently small, holding all **`2k`** on-demand `Iterable`s is not the issue.

About non-determinisitic iterating order - you are totally right, so solution is correct for only deterministic order `Iterable`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. It also takes care of the randomization (don't neglect this!) in a reasonably efficient manner, i.e. O(n) instead of O(n log(n)) required for the more naive approach using a random shuffle/permutation of the data.

```
import scala.util.Random

def testTrainDataList[T](
  data: Seq[T], 
  k: Int, 
  seed: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
): Seq[(Iterable[T], Iterable[T])] = {
  def createKeys(n: Int, k: Int) = {
    val groupSize = n/k
    val rem = n % k
    val cumCounts = Array.tabulate(k){ i =>
      if (i < rem) (i + 1)*(groupSize + 1) else (i + 1)*groupSize + rem
    }
    val rng = new Random(seed)
    for (count <- n to 1 by -1) yield {
      val j = rng.nextInt(count)
      val i = cumCounts.iterator.zipWithIndex.find(_._1 > j).map(_._2).get
      for (s <- i until k) cumCounts(s) -= 1
    }
  }

  val keys = createKeys(data.length, k)
  for (i <- 0 until k) yield {
    val testIterable = new Iterable[T] {
      def iterator = (keys.iterator zip data.iterator).filter(_._1 == i).map(_._2)
    }
    val trainIterable = new Iterable[T] {
      def iterator = (keys.iterator zip data.iterator).filter(_._1 != i).map(_._2)
    }
    (testIterator, trainIterator)
  }
}
```

Note the way I define `testIterable` and `trainIterable`. This makes your test/train sets lazy and non-memoized, which I gathered is what you wanted.

Example usage:

```
val data = 'a' to 'z'
for (((testData, trainData), index) <- testTrainDataList(data, 4).zipWithIndex) {
  println(s"index = $index")
  println("test: " + testData.mkString(", "))
  println("train: " + trainData.mkString(", "))
}

//index = 0
//test: i, l, o, q, v, w, y
//train: a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, j, k, m, n, p, r, s, t, u, x, z
//
//index = 1
//test: a, d, e, h, n, r, z
//train: b, c, f, g, i, j, k, l, m, o, p, q, s, t, u, v, w, x, y
//
//index = 2
//test: b, c, m, t, u, x
//train: a, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, n, o, p, q, r, s, v, w, y, z
//
//index = 3
//test: f, g, j, k, p, s
//train: a, b, c, d, e, h, i, l, m, n, o, q, r, t, u, v, w, x, y, z
```